# Error starting OpenSearch using Colima on Mac m1

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, apple-m1, colima

I am getting this error.

This is my docker compose.

```
image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.5.0
environment:
  - discovery.type=single-node
  - plugins.security.disabled=true
  - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
  nofile:
    soft: 65536
    hard: 65536
volumes:
  - ./data/opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
ports:
  - 9200:9200
  - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
networks:
  - net
```

`

> Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741450445Z    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741451610Z    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106) ~[?:?]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741452816Z    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741453980Z    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:397) ~[?:?]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741456392Z    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:700) ~[?:?]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741473899Z    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:807) ~[?:?]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741477018Z    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:793) ~[?:?]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741494401Z    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:313) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741607722Z    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:251) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741610051Z    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:311) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741611506Z    at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:456) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741612878Z    at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:356) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741614209Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741615540Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741616829Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:404) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741618118Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.init(OpenSearch.java:180) ~[opensearch-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741619324Z    ... 6 more
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.741472319Z uncaught exception in thread [main]
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742264650Z OpenSearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes];
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742275212Z Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/opensearch/data/nodes
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742277125Z    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742278539Z    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742279953Z    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742284486Z    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:397)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742286274Z    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:700)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742287480Z    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:807)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742288728Z    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:793)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742289934Z    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:313)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742291140Z    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:251)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742292470Z    at org.opensearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:311)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742293718Z    at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:456)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742300496Z    at org.opensearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:356)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742301744Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:242)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742302950Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:242)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742304156Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:404)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742305279Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.init(OpenSearch.java:180)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742306443Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.execute(OpenSearch.java:171)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742307649Z    at org.opensearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:104)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742308855Z    at org.opensearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:138)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742310061Z    at org.opensearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:101)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742311225Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.main(OpenSearch.java:137)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742312390Z    at org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch.main(OpenSearch.java:103)
> 2024-03-21T11:06:56.742313554Z For complete error details, refer to the log at /usr/share/opensearch/logs/docker-cluster.log`

Have tried accessing using user id 1000 using userns_mode, other than that couldn't find anything else on internet